# Setting Cookies to a PHP Like dislike count

Tags: javascript, cookies, count

I am not a Java Script Pro, so please Help me to Set Cookies to my Like Unlike Counter that's populated based on While loop from the MySQL DB.

From a PHP (MySQL) using MySQLi driver the Like Unlike count is called thus:

```
    <span class="glyphicon-thumbs-up" onClick="Rating(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,1,'like_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')" ></span>&nbsp;

<span class="glyphicon-thumbs-down" onClick="Rating(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,0,'dislike_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')" ></span>&nbsp;
```

Please help me, when ever a user clicks on a Like or unlike to set a 1 Day delay for the User for his/her Next like please. I need to do this using Cookies based on the ID it's added to the Below code in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Rating(id,type,target){
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'rating.php',
    data:'id='+id+'&type='+type,
    success:function(msg){
    if(msg == 'err'){
    alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
    }else{
    $('#'+target).html(msg);
    }
    }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Can some one set a Cookie code to the above ajax code added above so it will set a Delay based on ID before the Next like?

Appreciate the Help.

Comment: You might want to consider keeping track of a user's past likes in the database and not rely on cookies. Cookies are client side and can be manipulated. And thats if they are enabled by the user at all. Sounds like this should be server side.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but for this I need to do on cookies so appreciate if one could help by code to add to my Ajax code a one day stop time after vote based on id pls